# google script - send table by email with values from a loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a web app which take some inputs and I need to write those inputs in a sheet and then send an email with those inputs.

My code is below, I removed some lines in the code because they are not relevant. Assume pnArray and qArray are two arrays with values (strings and numbers).

The problem statement is how to create a HTML table in the loop below and then send that table by email.

```
function submitInfo() {
    
  var table = "<table><tbody><tr><td>Part Number</td><td>Packs</td></tr>";
  var pnArray = ["string1","string2"];
  var qArray = [1,2]; 
    
    for(var i =0;i<pnArray.length;i++){
    
    var pn = pnArray[i];
    var q = qArray[i];
      
    table += Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td>', pn);
    table += Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td></tr>', q);
     
      
    }
    table+="</tbody></table>";
    GmailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "test", null, {htmlBody:table});
}
```

Comment: I need a [mcve] with no undefined variables.

Comment: Hi, I edited as above, is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function submitInfo() {
  var html = "<table><tr><td>Part Number</td><td>Packs</td></tr>";
  var pnArray = ["string1","string2"];
  var qArray = [1,2]; 
  pnArray.forEach(function(pn,i){html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>'pn,qArray[i]);});
    table+="</table>";
    GmailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com","test",null,{htmlBody:html});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I kept my loop format as I am having other code in my script, it does send the email, but the format of the table is off. Even with your code, there are no borders. How can I change the style?

Comment: try using an inline style attribute in the th and td

Comment: not sure how.. I added <table style="border-color: #d8d3db;"> but still no showing the border. I used similar syntax to center the text and it works. So the issue seems only for the borders?

Comment: I don't really send any html email.  But my guess is may style='border: 1px solid #d8d3db'